# How to use css files or js in Area on ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, area, static-files

You know ASP .NET Core MVC has a **wwwroot** static files folder. I need to put my **custom js, css** etc. into **Content** folder **under Areas** folder. Anyone tried this before or anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the structure of our area is as follows :

[image]

You need to Copy these codes to the Configure section in Startup under the 
`app.UseStaticFiles()`

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
   {
     FileProvider = new 
     PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
     "Areas\\Foo\\Content")),
      RequestPath = new PathString("/Foo/Content")
   });
```

and link the file like below :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Foo/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: This approach worked for local testing - however when deployed to azure setting the script as Content didn't deploy. Under the azure environment the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is looking for file in wwwroot folder i.e. D:\home\site\wwwroot\Areas\Foo\Content\